# IdentityServer Sign out of one app(require new login) but stay signed in with another app

Tags: angularjs, authentication, identityserver3

I would like to implement a SPA that has an inactivity timeout that would require a user to re-authenticate before they can use the SPA again but I do not want to log out of IdentityServer because that will kick them out of any other application they may be actively using. How can I do this without making it possibly for the user to just change some JS so they never have an inactivity timeout? I am using AngularJS within an AspNet core project that will call AspNet apis that are on separate URLs.

Comment: I noticed that Gmail and Google Wallet implement this functionality. Wallet will log out after some time but gmail will not, and when you go back to wallet you must re-authenticate.

Answer (score 2):

When sending the user back to IdentityServer for re-authentication, you can pass the prompt=login OIDC parameter. This will force them to re-authenticate at IdSvr.

Comment: Yes and that works very well but that will require the user to log in everytime they visit the app. How do I make it only prompt login in certain situations. I am also wondering, can't the user just go in and remove prompt login in the JS, then they would not be required to login again.

Comment: You can use the max_age param instead, asking for the user to login if they haven't in a certain amount of time. Check the docs/spec.